# How to pass Bundle Arguments when Navigate to Route (String) instead of ID-based?

Tags: android, android-navigation

In https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#bundle, it provide us an option to navigate to a destinity and also provide bundle arguments

```
val bundle = bundleOf("amount" to amount)
view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.confirmationAction, bundle)
```

However, if my destiny is defined by a String-based route, e.g.

```
object navRoutes {
    const val home = "home"
    const val dashboard = "dashboard"
    const val notifications = "notifications"
}
```

When I navigate to it, I cannot supply the bundle.

```
val bundle = bundleOf("amount" to amount)
view.findNavController().navigate(navRoute.home, bundle)
```

The reason is there is

```
    public open fun navigate(@IdRes resId: Int, args: Bundle?)
```

But there's no

```
    public fun navigate(route: String, args: Bundle?)
```

How can I supply my bundle to a String-base route navigation??

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the destination using `controller.findDestination()` and navigate using the `navigate(@IdRes resId: Int, args: Bundle?, navOptions: NavOptions?)` method.

For ex.

```
val controller = view.findNavController()
val destination = controller.findDestination(navRoute.home)
val bundle = bundleOf("amount" to amount)
controller.navigate(destination.id, bundle)
```